# Backing up post install; rsync breaks

Tags: backup, rsync, reinstall

I use the following command for backup, but if I do a clean install of Fedora, copy over all my backed up files, then backup again, it copies them even though they are unchanged. Why? Can I avoid this?

```
rsync -tvr --modify-window=1 --cvs-exclude \
   --exclude-from '/run/media/user/32GB/.exclude' --progress \
   /home/user/Documents/* /run/media/alex/32GB/
```

Comment: You can add `-v` switches to `rsync` which will show you why it's doing things that do not make sense to you. You can add multiple switches to make it even more verbose. `rsync -vvv ...` for example.

Comment: See, but it won't do it now. I'd have to possibly reinstall and then backup AGAIN...a bit silly. Thanks for the input, though.

Answer (score -1):

Add the `-c` option to your command line.

From the rsync man page:

> -c, --checksum
>
> This changes the way rsync checks if the files have been changed and are in need of a  transfer. Without this option, rsync uses a lqquick checkrq that (by default) checks if each file's size and time of last modification match between the sender and receiver. This option changes this to compare a 128-bit checksum for each file that has a matching size. Generating the checksums means that both sides will expend a lot of disk I/O reading all the data in the files in the transfer (and this is prior to any reading that will be done to transfer changed files), so this can slow things down significantly. 
>   The sending side generates its checksums while it is doing the file-system
>       scan that builds the list of the available files. The receiver generates its checksums when it is scanning for changed files, and will checksum any file that has the same size as the corresponding sender's file: files with either a changed size or a changed checksum are selected for transfer.

Comment: This is even worse, now it just hangs once it says `sending incremental file list`